# Xamarin.Forms Picker Default Value

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp, xamarin.forms, picker

I have date picker and i am populating it dynamically via a web service.

```
<Picker x:Name="picker" Title="Select Something" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}"></Picker>
```

I set the `Title` property as above but for UWP it shows up as a Label. How can i set it as a default value/prompt for UWP ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Pickers don't have any kind of  'placeholder' functionality, you would have to have a an extra item in your source binding that you could differentiate from the other items in your source as the default selected index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Digitalsa1nt said, `Picker` don't have `PlaceholderText` property. However, you could add this property via [custom renderer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/).

**CustomPicker.cs**

```
public class CustomPicker : Picker
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty PlaceHolderProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
propertyName: "PlaceHolder",
eturnType: typeof(string),
declaringType: typeof(CustomPicker),
defaultValue: default(string));

    public string PlaceHolder
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(PlaceHolderProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PlaceHolderProperty, value); }
    }

}
```

Implement `CustomPickerRenderer` in your uwp client project.

**CustomPickerRenderer.cs**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomPicker), typeof(CustomPickerRenderer))]

namespace XamarinPickerDefaultValueTest.UWP
{
    public class CustomPickerRenderer : PickerRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            var element = Element as CustomPicker;

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.PlaceholderText = element.PlaceHolder;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
<local:CustomPicker PlaceHolder="Picker something" x:Name="picker"/>
```

[image]